# Using ViewData to change button color

Tags: c#

I have a program that will generate buttons labled on distinc toy types on a data base. When user clicks on any of these buttons, the page will popupate using a query. This feature is working fine. I've used foreach razor on my view to loop through a list of toy types to create the buttons.
The problem is that I'm trying to use ViewData approach to change the color (bootstrap btn-success) when user click on any button to indicate that that button was clicked.
There are any way to use ViewData to change the color for the button that is clicked?

Tried to use ViewData to change the color but, I think because I have used foreach to generate the buttons, all buttons were created with the same class. When I click on any button, all buttons change its colors to green.

This is my View:

```
@model toysApp.Models.ToyManager

<div class="row my-3">
    <div class="col">
        <h2>Toy Listing</h2>        
        <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SelectType">
            <div class="btn-group">
                @foreach (var item in Model.toysType)
                {
                    <input type="submit" asp-for="typePicked" class="btn btn-outline-secondary @ViewData["btnStyle"]" value="@item" />
                }
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ToyID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Price</th>
                    <th scope="col">Qty</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.toys)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.toyID</td>
                    <td>@item.name</td>
                    <td>@item.price</td>
                    <td>@item.qty</td>
                </tr>                    
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Model:

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace toysApp.Models {

    public class ToyManager {

        // database connectivity variables
        private MySqlConnection dbConnection;
        private MySqlCommand dbCommand;
        private MySqlDataReader dbReader;

        private const string CONNECTION_STRING = "Server=localhost;Database="";Uid="";Pwd="";"

        private List<Toy> _toys;
        // this string is to hold the value from the list string
        private string type;
        private List<String> _toysType;

        public string typePicked {get; set;} = null;


        public List<Toy> toys {
            get {
                return _toys;
            }
        }        

        public List<String> toysType {
            get {
                return _toysType;
            }
            set {
                _toysType = value;
            }
        }


        public ToyManager() {
            // construct list of Toys objects
            _toys = new List<Toy>();
            _toysType = new List<String>();

            // construct DB objects for use
            dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
            dbCommand = new MySqlCommand("", dbConnection); 

        }

        // function to grab the DISTINCT type name from DB and store da value in typePicked variable
        public void toysTypes() {
            try {
                dbConnection.Open();
                dbCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM tblToys", dbConnection);
                dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (dbReader.Read()) {
                    type = dbReader["type"].ToString();

                    // add toys to the toys list
                    _toysType.Add(type);
                }

                dbReader.Close();

                if (typePicked == null) {
                    typePicked = _toysType[0];
                    dbConnection.Close();
                    toysInventory();
                }

            } finally {
                dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        public void toysInventory() {
            try {
                dbConnection.Open();
                dbCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblToys WHERE type = ?typePicked";
                dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?typePicked", typePicked);
                dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (dbReader.Read()) {
                    Toy toys = new Toy();
                    toys.toyID = dbReader["toyID"].ToString();
                    toys.type = dbReader["type"].ToString();
                    toys.name = dbReader["name"].ToString();
                    toys.price = Convert.ToDouble(dbReader["price"]);
                    toys.qty = Convert.ToInt32(dbReader["qty"]);
                    toys.description = dbReader["description"].ToString();

                    // add toys to the toys list
                    _toys.Add(toys);

                }

            } finally {
                dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, finally, this is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using toysApp.Models;

namespace toysApp.Controllers {

    public class HomeController : Controller {

        public IActionResult Index() {
            ToyManager toyManager = new ToyManager();
            toyManager.toysTypes();
            return View(toyManager);
        }

        public IActionResult SelectType(ToyManager toyManager) {
            toyManager.toysTypes();
            toyManager.toysInventory();
            ViewData["btnStyle" + toyManager.typePicked] = "btn-success";
            return View("Index", toyManager);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your classes and achieve this without view data as alternative solution.

```
//// c#
public class ToyType
{
    public string TypeName {get; set;}
    public string TypeClass {get; set;}
}

public List<ToyType> toyTypes {get; set;}

//// razor
@foreach (var toyType in Model.toyTypes)
{
    <input type="submit" asp-for="typePicked" class="btn btn-outline-secondary @toyType.TypeClass" value="@toyType.TypeName" />
}
```

If you consider your case, you are always assigning same value to different keys in view bag

```
ViewData["btnStyle" + toyManager.typePicked] = "btn-success";
```

And other issue is you are accessing that wrong too

```
@ViewData["btnStyle"]
```

access the view data using same key.

Answer (score 0):

Late but maybe help someone. Get rid of the for each and use a for loop. So every button has a different view data value. Then see if it matches in the controller. It will change the button clicked to whatever class you wanted.

Controller:

```
        ViewData["btnStyle" + toyManager.selectedType] = 
        "btn-success";
```

Index:

```
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.selectedToyType.Count(); i++) 
   {
                
    <input asp-for="selectedType" id="@i" type="submit" 
      class="btn  @ViewData["btnStyle" + 
      @Model.selectedToyType[i].type]" 
      value="@Model.selectedToyType[i].type"/>
                
    }
```